# Is it possible to access variable in a labda expression? c#

Tags: c#, lambda, scope

I want to be able to access "co" in my lambda expression. Is it possible to do so? if yes how? or if not, what should I do instead?

I want to pass a block of code in my function "Do" where I would be able to use the variables in the scope of "Do".

Please ask me any question if you don't know what im talking about, ill try to explain better.

```
    public static type Do<type>(Func<type> fun)
    {
        OracleConnection co = null;
        type ret = default(type);
        try
        {
            co = CreateCo();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            ret = fun();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseCo(co);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static class Get
    {
        public static class Question
        {
            public static string byId()
            {
                //This lambda expression
                return Do<string>(() => 
                { co./*here I can't access my object: why? how? */ });
            }
        }
    }
```

I will update this post with the answer when I get one:
->[One answer that work !!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43483391/7886556)

Comment: `co` is declared in another class (at least it looks that way from your code). You would need to either make it a public property of the class where it's currently declared and then access it from your other class, or pass it into the `Get` class through a constructor or method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand, what you exactly want.

But if you call:

```
 return Do<string>(() => { });
```

the `() => {}` represents a function with lamda expression. But the function is indepented from your type declaration. In your type declaration you have a function as parameter, but this function is indepented from your type.

I think, that is the reason, why you don't have access to the "co".

Update:

Is that a solution for you?

```
 public static class Get
{
    public static class Question
    {
        public static string byId()
        {
            Func<OracleConnection, string> func1 = (co) => co.ToString();


            return Do<string>(func1);
        }
    }
}

 public static type Do<type>(Func<OracleConnection, type> fun)
    {
        OracleConnection co = null;
        type ret = default(type);
        try
        {
            co = CreateCo();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            ret = fun(co);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseCo(co);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Make sense, What I want to do is execute a block of code in the "Do" function and in this block of code be able to access the variables scoped in "Do".

Comment: I understand what you want. I have updated my answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Simply fantastic, thanks a lot, it work really nice.